# Jquery - Get Text Between 2 Div Tags

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

**UPDATED** : Please look code below:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='first'>whatever content</div>
    <div class='child1'></div>

    Paragraph 1
    <br>
    Paragraph 2

    <div class='child2'></div>
    <div class='child3'>whatever</div>

    i don't wanna this text

    <div class='last'>whatever</div>
</div>
```

How can I get text " **Paragraph 1 Paragraph 2** " 
without text "***I don't wanna this text***"
from that code?

Thank you.

NOTED :
**I CAN'T EDIT/CHANGE HTML CODE**.

Comment: For starters, put it in a p element.

Comment: Sorry, but in fact, i can't change the codes.

Comment: To bad. Have you tried Bill's solution? It'll take something icky like that.

Comment: Can't change the code? You mean just the HTML, right?

Comment: yes, i mean i can't edit HTML codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - How to get only a content without tags:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first">whatever content</div>
    <div class="child1"></div>

    Paragraph 1
    <br>
    Paragraph 2

    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3">whatever</div>

    Last Content

    <div class="last">whatever</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
var content = $('.parent').clone().children().remove().end().text();
alert(content);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vRbCw/3/

2- How to remove the content before `div.child3`:

**JQUERY:**

```
var appendSt = $('.child3').after('code:'),
    content  = $('.parent').clone().children().remove().end().text(),
    reg      = content.replace(/code:([^xyz]+)/, '');
alert(reg);
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/sBSRH/

Get The Text Of Element Without Child Element: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Your answer is near my expectation. But if i only want output "Paragraph 1 Paragraph 2" without "...", how can i do?

Answer (score 3):

You should really look into doing something completely different. However, you can get text nodes by using `.contents()` and checking to see if the `nodeType` is `3`.

```
var textNodes = $('.parent').contents().filter(function(){
  return this.nodeType === 3 && /[a-z]/g.test(this.nodeValue);
});
```

I'm only returning textNodes with at least one letter inside of it.

http://jsbin.com/eziqil/1/edit

You can wrap it up in a span to style it if you'd like by using `.wrap()` on the collection.

http://jsbin.com/eziqil/2/edit

Comment: This is _why_ you put it in a p element.

Comment: Absolutely! I answer these under the impression they have no control over the HTML.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I answer partly for the next guy who reads it.

Comment: Haha, which is why I said: "You should really look into doing something completely different".

Comment: Sorry, i tried your solution but unused text appeared in my result. I have been updated the question about my second problem above. Thanks.

Comment: For those who don't know...the bit that matches a single letter is actually a single lower case letter.  To make it more flexible it can be changed slightly to [a-zA-A0-9] or maybe using character classes.  The point is that if this block isn't working for you..that could be why.