# get text between 2 div tags in python

Tags: python

I'm making a script that gets bitcoin prices from multiple sites, and on one of the sites the text is between 2 div tags.

I tried multiple solutions but nothing worked,
however I found the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982776/jquery-get-text-between-2-div-tags) and this is exactly what I need but in python

Note: the text is updating every 2 seconds on the site

this is what i need to get

```html
<div data-bn-type="text" class="css-g80xfv" style="direction: ltr;">$19,490.20</div>
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

site - https://www.binance.com/en

Xpath - `//*[@id="__APP"]/div[2]/main/div/div[4]/div/a[2]/div[2]/div`

I know there's an API on this site but I just want to get the price nothing else

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: BeautifulSoup extract string between div tag by its class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289966/python-beautifulsoup-extract-string-between-div-tag-by-its-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) since the actual price information on that page is loaded dynamically, here is an example that gets an update every `2` seconds:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from decimal import Decimal
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

BASE_URL = 'https://www.binance.com/en'
BITCOIN_HREF = '/en/trade/BTC_BUSD'
LAST_PRICE_COLUMN_CLASS = 'css-g80xfv'
WAIT_SECONDS = 2

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    for _ in range(5): # replace with `while True:` if you want to get updates "indefinitely"
        driver.get(BASE_URL)

        time.sleep(WAIT_SECONDS)

        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
        btc_a_tag = soup.find('a', href=BITCOIN_HREF)
        btc_price_string = btc_a_tag.find('div', class_=LAST_PRICE_COLUMN_CLASS).text
        btc_price_decimal = Decimal(btc_price_string.strip('$').replace(',', ''))
        print(f"btc_price_string={btc_price_string}, btc_price_decimal={btc_price_decimal}")

    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example Output:**

```
btc_price_string=$19,306.29, btc_price_decimal=19306.29
btc_price_string=$19,307.85, btc_price_decimal=19307.85
btc_price_string=$19,308.18, btc_price_decimal=19308.18
btc_price_string=$19,308.41, btc_price_decimal=19308.41
btc_price_string=$19,308.18, btc_price_decimal=19308.18
```